# Using Shell, How can I read one text file's value and enter it into running crontab as input?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, cron

I want to run one cronjob in which I need to supply input. For this input I have one text file. How can I read that text file data and supply it as input into cronjob?

I am running one cron job with .sh file. which needs input data 2-3 times while running. The data stands into text1.txt, text2.txt, etc.

Now, I want to read data from these text files and insert it as a input in running cronjob. Crontab file execution waits with "expect" command. and it expects some data to go ahead, and that data is residing in a text file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So if I understand correctly, you run some script as cronjob; so somewhere in that script you can say:

```
X=`cat file`
```

or you can add `cat file | grep for something` to get just one line from your file

and later use $X for expected input.

Comment: Please do not use idiosyncratic capitalization.

Comment: @Pascal Cuoq Sorry, English is not my native language, I was thought in school to always capitalize: I, You, We etc. But if it's accepted style here - I will try to keep lowercase in future, but can't promise, it's automatic habit, you know :)